How can I send a string from a Python script to a webserver?
I need a python script to send a string to a webserver if a condition is true. To check the condition, I have an if loop. However, I'm not sure what commands to use to send the string to the webserver.
I've tried the requests library, but it keeps returning Not found.
My current script includes this code to send the string.
import requests
url = 'http://192.168._._'
value = "string"
query = {'input1': 'value'}
res = requests.post(url, data=query)
print(str(res.text))

My webserver code looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ESP Input Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1074.0" data-gr-ext-installed data-gr-ext-disabled="forever">
    <form action="/get">
      " input1: "
      <input type="text" name="input1">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

The resulting webserver is a single input box and submit button. I need the Python script to enter a value into the input box and submit it. Is the requests library the best way to accomplish this? Or is there a better way?

The HTML form results in a GET request to '/get', the python program results in a POST request to '/'. Which one is correct? Maybe try requests.get('http://192.168._._/get', data=query).

Thanks! It's not submitting anything as an input to the webserver, though. The response is the entire html code.

Check your webserver access log, you should see something like GET /get?input1=value

{'input1': 'value'} should be {'input1': value}. The quotes around value prevent it from using the variable.
